# Confused about command line options for Linux mkfs

Tags: 20.04, files, filesystem, disk, disk-formatting

I am formatting a new drive on Ubuntu 20.04, and I am at the step where I format the drive to ext4.  One article (https://linuxize.com/post/fdisk-command-in-linux/) says to do this:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F /dev/sdb1
```

The article doesn't say what the -F option is, and there is no -F option in the Linux man page for mkfs at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mkfs.8.html.

Another article (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-partition-and-format-storage-devices-in-linux) says to use the -L option:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -L datapartition /dev/sda1
```

but again it doesn't say what -L does.

Another article (https://linuxhandbook.com/mkfs-command/) said to use the -t option

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb
```

-t is listed on the Linux man page with this:  "Specify the type of filesystem to be built. If not specified, the default filesystem type (currently ext2) is used."  I don't want ext2, I want ext4.

So my question is:  do I want to choose -F, -L or -t?  Where can I find an explanation of those other command line options shown above that are not covered in the Linux man page for mkfs?

Comment: see `man mkfs.ext4 ` You first want to set label to gpt, so using gpt partitioning. Then want to create partitions. And then format partition(s). I have always used gparted either from live installer or gparted live ISO booted.  I do prefer to label all partitions. With gpt there are two labels, one for file system & one for partition. And to somewhat confuse things the parted command uses label to say if gpt or old MBR(msdos). `sudo parted /dev/sdX mklabel gpt` Do not format a drive, just partition(s). And if bootable, best to have ESP as first partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the correct manpage with `man mkfs.ext4` or [online](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mkfs.ext4) where these options are explained:

```
-F
    Force mke2fs to create a filesystem, even if the specified device is not a 
    partition on a block special device, or if other parameters do not make sense.
    In order to force mke2fs to create a filesystem even if the filesystem
    appears to be in use or is mounted (a truly dangerous thing to do), this
    option must be specified twice. 

-L new-volume-label
    Set the volume label for the filesystem to new-volume-label. The maximum
    length of the volume label is 16 bytes. 

-t fs-type
    Specify the filesystem type (i.e., ext2, ext3, ext4, etc.) that is to be
    created. If this option is not specified, mke2fs will pick a default either
    via how the command was run (for example, using a name of the form mkfs.ext2,
    mkfs.ext3, etc.) or via a default as defined by the /etc/mke2fs.conf(5) file.
    This option controls which filesystem options are used by default, based on
    the fstypes configuration stanza in /etc/mke2fs.conf(5).
```